# How would I say "the teachers"?

Tags: articles

Would I use "des profs" or "les profs"? I know that "les profs" would literally mean "the teachers", but isn't "the teachers" an unspecified amount, and shouldn't we therefore use "des"?

Comment: Can you provide more context? "Les profs" could both mean "the teachers" ("the teachers are nice this year" = "les profs sont bien cette année") or "teachers" in general ("I hate teachers" = "je déteste les profs"). Note that "prof" is slang for "professeur".

Comment: You are asking if "the teachers" are an unspecified amount" which is something we will not answer on French Language, and which is not correct. You need to clarify this first and rephrase your question then.

Comment: @Destal : *Prof* slang ? Bon... j'aurais pas dit ça. Barbacole, pendu, archipédant, corps de pompe... etc... oui! Mais prof... bon!

Comment: @aCOSwt C'est vrai que c'est peut-être exagéré de dire que c'est de l'argot, disons que ça n'en est plus.

Answer (score 2):

"The teachers" = "les profs". "Des profs" means "some teachers" so I don't see why you would use that instead. If you mean "teachers" in general, that's still "les profs".